# How to store files in private IPFS Network in a content addressable archive manner?

Tags: nft, ipfs, erc-1155

I have created a private IPFS network and I want to store files in this network in a content addressable archive manner. So that I get same URL for all tokens which would be only differentiated by their token IDs.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: sorry but you need to look for tutorials, no one will answer a general question

Comment: check maybe this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTnDTWHsbIs